# how to make my images responsive?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hi all using twitters bootstrap: http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/base-css.html#tables

I am wandering how I can stop this happening: http://img823.imageshack.us/img823/6606/screenshotfrom201306071.png 
I want the images to resize with the window until it gets bumped up above the text from bootsrap.

Link for it: http://www.prxa.info/articles/category/1 User: test.prxa. pass: test

I NEED images to have a max of 350px here as some images people include are massive and have to be resized to not mess it all up.

Here is my custom css for the thumbnail area and the images inside:

```
.thumbnail
{
    width: 350px;
    height: 220px;
    display: table-cell; 
    vertical-align: middle;
}

img.tagline-img
{
    max-width: 350px;
    max-height: 220px;
}
```

Comment: I see that you're responding to everyone saying that the `max-width` doesn't work (firefox has nothing to do with it).  That **is** a correct answer, and if making the change doesn't fix it for you it means you have other issues.  Use Inspect Element and see whether those properties are taking affect or if they're being overwritten by some other styles.  Here's a super simple [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zDSS6/) that illustrates it.

Comment: Seems no one payed attention the "thumbnail" class I have which encases the image...remove the hardcoded width seems to have fixed it.

Comment: Why are you doing this through CSS? Determine the width/height on the server and then rescale it appropriately in the width/height tags. I do not like to see the `width` property utlized on images when such a tag already exists within the `<img>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Your site in firefox with width:100%]Not the best responsive technique but it will make it fit

Just use

```
img.tagline-img { 
   width:100%;
}
```

Just tested on your site

Comment: I just added an screen shot of your site with 100% width on the img.tagline-img

Comment: I get this: http://img543.imageshack.us/img543/3512/screenshotfrom201306072.png yet it works in chrome?!

Answer (score 0):

taken from bootstrap :

```
img{
    border:0;
    max-width:100%; /* Part 1:Set a maxium relative to the parent */
    width:auto\9; /* IE7-8 need help adjusting responsive images */
    height:auto; /* Part 2:Scale the height according to the width,
        otherwise you get stretching */
-ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic
}
```